# How to reset and set up timer function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a quiz app with a controller where I should set up a timer that should be counting for 30s, and then stop the quiz if there is no activity in that time. If there is some activity in the meantime it should be reset and start counting again. I have set up web socket listeners for that. How should I do the timer setup?

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('quiz.controllers')
.controller('MultiPlayerQuestionController', function(
  $scope,
  $rootScope,
  $state,
  $stateParams,
  $timeout,
  UserService,
  QuizService,
  InviteService,
  MessageService,
  SocketService
) {
  $scope.user = UserService.get();
  $scope.quiz = QuizService.getCurrent();
  $scope.opponent = $scope.user.player.id == $scope.quiz.players[0].id
    ? $scope.quiz.players[1]
    : $scope.quiz.players[0]
    || null;

  $scope.currentQuestion = {};
  $scope.answer = {};
  $scope.showAlternatives = false;
  $scope.showCorrect = false;
  $scope.isLast = false;
  $scope.opponentAnswered = false;

  var timeouts = {
    stop: null,
    activate: null
  };

  var startTime,
      loadBar,
      initiated = false;

  // Opponent has answered; update score display
  SocketService.socket.removeAllListeners('gameEvent:opponentAnswer');
  SocketService.socket.on('gameEvent:opponentAnswer', function(message) {
    $scope.opponentAnswered = true;
    QuizService.updateOpponentScore(message.data.totalScore);
  });

  // Next question is triggered from all players having answered
  SocketService.socket.removeAllListeners('gameEvent:nextQuestion');
  SocketService.socket.on('gameEvent:nextQuestion', function(message) {
    $timeout(function() {
      QuizService.setCurrentQuestion(message.data.question);
      setupQuestion(message.data.question);
    }, 3000);
  });

  // Game is finished, go to score screen
  SocketService.socket.removeAllListeners('gameEvent:quizFinished');
  SocketService.socket.on('gameEvent:quizFinished', function(message) {
    stopQuiz();

    $timeout(function() {
      $state.go('multiplayer.score');
    }, 3000);
  });

  // An opponent has quit, go to score screen
  SocketService.socket.removeAllListeners('gameEvent:opponentQuit');
  SocketService.socket.on('gameEvent:opponentQuit', function(message) {
    stopQuiz();
    MessageService.alertMessage('Motstanderen din har enten gitt opp eller blitt frakoblet.');
    $state.go('multiplayer.score');
  });

  // Disconnected. Go back to home screen.
  SocketService.socket.removeAllListeners('reconnecting');
  SocketService.socket.on('reconnecting', function() {
    MessageService.alertMessage('Du har mistet tilkoblingen. Spillet har blitt avbrutt.');
    SocketService.socket.removeAllListeners('reconnecting');
    $state.go('main.front');
  });

  // The app was paused (closed), equals giving up.
  var pauseEvent = $rootScope.$on('app:paused', function() {
    QuizService.giveUpCurrent($scope.user.player);

    var resumeEvent = $rootScope.$on('app:resumed', function() {
      stopQuiz();
      $state.go('multiplayer.score');
      resumeEvent();
    });

    pauseEvent();
  });

  /**
   * Give up the current quiz.
   */
  $scope.giveUp = function (player) {
    MessageService.confirm('Ønsker du å avbryte quizen?').then(function(result) {
      if (result) {
        QuizService.giveUpCurrent(player);
        $state.go('multiplayer.score', {}, { reload: true });
        stopQuiz();
      }
    });
  };

  /**
   * Go to next question for current quiz.
   */
  $scope.nextQuestion = function() {
    $timeout.cancel(timeouts.stop);
    $timeout.cancel(timeouts.activate);

    QuizService.nextQuestion().$promise.then(function(question) {
      setupQuestion(QuizService.getCurrentQuestion());
    });
  };

  /**
   * Finish quiz.
   */
  $scope.finish = function() {
    QuizService.finish();
    $state.go('multiplayer.score');
  };

  /**
   * Choose an alternative (aka answer current question).
   */
  $scope.chooseAlternative = function(alternative) {
    if (!$scope.showAlternatives || $scope.showCorrect) {
      return;
    }

    var answerTime = Date.now() - startTime;

    $scope.answer = alternative;
    QuizService.answer(alternative, answerTime);

    if (timeouts.stop) {
      $timeout.cancel(timeouts.stop);
    }

    stopQuestion();
  };

  /**
   * Set up a new question - change data and start countdown to activate question.
   */
  var setupQuestion = function(question) {
    $scope.showAlternatives = false;
    $scope.showCorrect = false;
    $scope.currentQuestion = question;
    $scope.answer = {};
    $scope.isLast = parseInt($scope.quiz.questionCount) == parseInt($scope.currentQuestion.questionNumber);

    var prepareTime = 5000;

    var newLoadBar = loadBar.cloneNode(true);
    loadBar.parentNode.replaceChild(newLoadBar, loadBar);
    loadBar = newLoadBar;

    setAnimationDuration(loadBar, 'loadbar', prepareTime);
    timeouts.activate = $timeout(activateQuestion, prepareTime);
  };

  /**
   * A question timed out; stop and send empty answer.
   */
  var questionTimeout = function() {
    // Delay answering by a random delay between 0 and 500ms.
    $timeout(function() {
      stopQuestion();
      QuizService.noAnswer($scope.currentQuestion.id);
    }, Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 1));
  };

  /**
   * Activate the current question: show alternatives and open answering.
   */
  var activateQuestion = function() {
    $scope.showAlternatives = true;
    var timeToAnswer = 10000;
    startTime = Date.now();

    var newLoadBar = loadBar.cloneNode(true);
    loadBar.parentNode.replaceChild(newLoadBar, loadBar);
    loadBar = newLoadBar;

    setAnimationDuration(newLoadBar, 'loadbar', timeToAnswer);
    timeouts.stop = $timeout(questionTimeout, timeToAnswer);
  };

  /**
   * Stop the current question and show the correct answer info.
   */
  var stopQuestion = function() {
    $scope.showCorrect = true;
    stopAnimation(loadBar);
    $timeout.cancel(timeouts.stop);
  };

  /**
   * End the current quiz.
   */
  var stopQuiz = function() {
    SocketService.socket.removeAllListeners('gameEvent:opponentAnswer');
    SocketService.socket.removeAllListeners('gameEvent:nextQuestion');
    SocketService.socket.removeAllListeners('gameEvent:quizFinished');
    SocketService.socket.removeAllListeners('gameEvent:opponentQuit');
    SocketService.socket.removeAllListeners('reconnecting');

    $timeout.cancel(timeouts.stop);
    $timeout.cancel(timeouts.activate);
  };

  /**
   * Set the animation duration for an element. Used to stop and start the
   * progress bar.
   */
  var setAnimationDuration = function(element, keyframes, duration) {
    var animationSetting = keyframes + ' ' + duration + 'ms linear';

    element.style.webkitAnimation = animationSetting;
    element.style.animation = animationSetting;
  }

  var stopAnimation = function(element) {
    element.style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
    element.style.animation = 'none';
  };

  if (!initiated) {
    initiated = true;
    loadBar = document.getElementById('load-bar');
    setupQuestion(QuizService.getCurrentQuestion());
  }


});
```

I have tried with calling the responseTimer function that I have made in my controller. At the begging of the file I am calling it like this:

```
responseTimer(30000);
```

And then later I am defining it like this:

```
var responseTimer = function (time) {
    responseTimer = $timeout(stopQuiz, time);
    console.log('Started timer');
  };

  var resetResponseTimer = function () {
      $timeout.cancel(responseTimer);
      responseTimer(30000);
      console.log("Timer reset");
  };
```

But I get an error:

> TypeError: responseTimer is not a function

Comment: Where you define the timer? Also special: var responseTimer = function (time) {
    responseTimer = $timeout(stopQuiz, time);
    console.log('Started timer');
  };   twoTimes "responseTimer"

Comment: which timer do you mean exactly?

Comment: the responseTimer

Comment: I am only defining it later after a call to it in my controller, how exactly should I do that, if you could help me I would be very greatful!

Comment: I miss the var responseTimer.... I think you're mixing variables an functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem comes from a scope conflict. In your code

```
// responseTimer is declared as a global function
var responseTimer = function (time) {

   // as the var keyword is not specify, scope of responseTimer becomes global and not local and overrides the previous declaration
   responseTimer = $timeout(stopQuiz, time);
```

That is why you get the error

```
 responseTimer is not a function
```

To solve the problem add the var keyword before the second declaration and name your variables appropriately. A good practice is to add an action verb when naming function/object's methods, in your case triggerResponseTimer as name of your function and responseTimer as name of the variable so final porposition would be:

```
var triggerResponseTimer = function (time) {

    var responseTimer = $timeout(stopQuiz, time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better use $intervall:
Here you will find a good sample:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/timeout-interval.html

Also good sample:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: But I don't need to call my function repeatedly I need to call it when I enter the controller and then reset the timer each time I get some response from web socket

Comment: Do you not like to show the timer count down in your page... that the user can see the time until end?

Comment: No, I only use the timer for my own purpuses, to see if I got any response from the backend API (web socket), if I don't get anything for 30s, then I would like to stop the quiz